# INFLUX DB 2.X: Failure writing points to database: partial write: points beyond retention policy

Tags: time-series, influxdb

Using INFLUX DB 2.0 I use the write API to insert one record with line protocol using postman.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=my-org&bucket=test&percision=s' \
--header 'Authorization: Token test' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'mem,host=host1 used_percent=23.43234543 1625392977'
```

I increased the retention period to one year.

[image]

And this results in:

```json
{
    "code": "unprocessable entity",
    "message": "failure writing points to database: partial write: points beyond retention policy dropped=1"
}
```

I have no clue why it still complains about the retention period as I use a timestamp of today. Any ideas on what this might be?

Comment: Hi, have you managed to fix this? I have the same issue. Checked timestamp of client container and influxdb container (using Docker here), and can't figure out what's the problem. If I use a bucket without infinite retention policy it works, but that's not what the both of us want.

Comment: It might have to do with line endings being appended. It might have to do with the retention period not being correct. If I recall correctly, I fixed it by using the cloud influx, strangely enough, that did the job.

Comment: This post is quite long ago, still I want to mention that there is a typo in the code above: not "percision" but "precision"